# How can I avoid a few seconds of blank video when using -vcodec copy?

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, video-codecs, video-conversion

I'm processing user-uploaded videos on a CentOS web server with ffmpeg. I need to convert each video to a standard size and format, then extract a 30-second sample clip from each video. I want to use the "-vcodec copy" flag in the extraction command to avoid encoding a second time.

This command works for my initial conversion:

```
ffmpeg -i uploaded.mov -f mp4 -vcodec libx264 -vpre medium -acodec libfaac -r 15 -b 360k -ab 48k -ar 22050 -s 480x320 formatted.mp4
```

And this *sometimes* works for the extraction:

```
ffmpeg -i formatted.mp4 -vcodec copy -acodec copy -ss 0 -t 30 formatted_sample.mp4
```

However, when I run the extraction command on some videos, the extracted sample clip starts with several seconds of blank video. The audio starts right away but the video doesn't start for 3-6 seconds.

To demonstrate the problem, I've uploaded two video clips and run the above commands on them. I created the first clip in Final Cut Express and encoded it with Handbrake before uploading to the web server:

1a) [uploaded clip](http://www.arlomedia.com/projects/ffmpeg/band.mp4)

1b) [converted with first command](http://www.arlomedia.com/projects/ffmpeg/band_formatted.mp4)

1c) [extracted with second command, missing first six seconds](http://www.arlomedia.com/projects/ffmpeg/band_formatted_sample.mp4)

By comparison, this second clip comes from Apple's website and does not show the problem:

2a) [uploaded clip](http://www.arlomedia.com/projects/ffmpeg/trailer.mov)

2b) [converted with first command](http://www.arlomedia.com/projects/ffmpeg/trailer_formatted.mp4)

2c) [extracted with second command, no problem](http://www.arlomedia.com/projects/ffmpeg/trailer_sample.mp4)

Can anyone see what's different about the two source clips? And if so, is there anything I can do in my conversion command so that when the extraction command runs, the clip is set up to avoid the missing video?

By the way, I initially had the problem with ffmpeg 0.6.1 installed from yum, but I upgraded to the latest git version and the problem remains.

Comment: How frequently do the keyframes occur in the source video?  If it doesn't start with a keyframe, the output may not be displaying anything until it hits the next one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Matt's suggestion about keyframes, combined with a timely hint posted to the ffmpeg mailing list, led me to a solution, although I'm not sure if it's the best solution.

First, I had to move the -ss and -t options in my extraction command so they appeared before the -i option. This causes the extraction to begin at the next earliest keyframe. So let's say I use -ss 25 -t 15 to extract from 0:25 to 0:40 in my clip, but I have keyframes every 10 seconds. Previously I would get a 15 second sample starting with 5 seconds of blank video. Now I will get a 20 second sample, running from 0:20 to 0:40, but with no blank video. In other words, I avoid the blank video but lose the accuracy of my clip selection.

To address that, I had to add the -g option to my conversion command to reformat the keyframes. I used -g 15 with -r 15 to make a keyframe every second. This allows me to choose sample locations to the nearest second, so -ss 25 -t 15 will give me the 15 second clip I asked for. I would expect the extra keyframes to make my full clip larger, but it is only about 2% larger in my tests, and that's a good trade-off for my project.

So, I changed my two commands above to:

```
ffmpeg -i uploaded.mov -f mp4 -vcodec libx264 -vpre medium -acodec libfaac -r 15 -g 15 -b 360k -ab 48k -ar 22050 -s 480x320 formatted.mp4

ffmpeg -ss 0 -t 30 -i formatted.mp4 -vcodec copy -acodec copy formatted_sample.mp4
```

And all seems well. If someone has a more efficient solution, please post and I'll change my chosen answer.

Comment: I didn't know that using different positions for the `ss` and `t` options would cause different outcomes.

Comment: Yes, I haven't seen any documentation on that, but someone posted to the ffmpeg-user list, "Keyframe seeking can occur if you ask it (ie you put -ss before -i)."

Comment: If I need precision shorter than 1 second, I'm not sure how to do that, especially given https://superuser.com/questions/1356862/how-to-add-additional-key-frames-to-video-using-ffmpeg